# TCP Sockets, "cannot assign requested address" and " Transport endpoint is already connected" errors

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am new to working with TCP sockets and I do not understand the errors I am getting when running my programs. I have two programs that when run simultaneous I would like to be able to pass messages between. The initial message gets through but then when trying to return another message I get two errors. When I run my first program the output is:

```
Input Message: hello

Waiting for incoming connections...

Connection accepted

Message Sent

Connection error: Transport endpoint is already connected
```

Now running the other program simultaneously gives:

```
Input Message: Hello Back

Connected

Message received

hello

Bind error: Cannot assign requested address
```

If anyone could explain these "cannot assign requested address" and " Transport endpoint is already connected" errors I would greatly appreciate it!! Thanks!

The first program is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_info, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char message[100];
    char incoming_message[100];

printf("Input Message: ");

fgets(message, 100, stdin);

        //create socket
        socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (socket_info == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        }

        //assign values
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( 1100 );

    int y=1;
        if(setsockopt(socket_info, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&y, sizeof(y)) == -1) {
    perror("set reuseaddr");
    return -1;
        }

        //binds socket
        if (bind(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind error");
        return 1;
        }

        //listen
        listen(socket_info , 5);

        //waiting for connection
        puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
        int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        //accept connection
        new_socket = accept(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if (new_socket < 0){
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //send message
        if( send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0) {
        perror("Send failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Message Sent");

        //connects
        if (connect(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connection error");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Connected");

        //Receive an incoming message
        if( recv(socket_info, incoming_message , sizeof(incoming_message) , 0) < 0) {
        perror("Received failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Message received");
    incoming_message[strlen(incoming_message)-1]=0;
        puts(incoming_message);

close(socket_info);
}
```

The second program is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int socket_info, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char incoming_message[100];
    char message[100];

printf("Input Message: ");

fgets(message, 100, stdin);

        //create socket
        socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (socket_info == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        }

        //assign values
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.21.8.178");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( 1100 );

        //connects
        if (connect(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connection error");
           return 1;
        }
        puts("Connected");

        //Receive an incoming message
        if( recv(socket_info, incoming_message , sizeof(incoming_message) , 0) < 0) {
        perror("Received failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Message received");
    incoming_message[strlen(incoming_message)-1]=0;
        puts(incoming_message);

    int y=1;
       if(setsockopt(socket_info, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&y, sizeof(y)) == -1) {
    perror("set reuseaddr");
    return -1;
        }

        //binds socket
        if (bind(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind error");
        return 1;
        }

        //listen
        listen(socket_info , 5);

        //waiting for connection
        puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
        int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        //accept connection
        new_socket = accept(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if (new_socket < 0){
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Connection accepted");

    //send message
        if( send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0) {
        perror("Send failed");
        return 1;
        }
        puts("Message Sent");

close(socket_info);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (connect(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    perror("Connection error");
    return 1;
    }

Connection error: Transport endpoint is already connected
```

I asssume `socket_info` above should be `new_socket`?

You can't connect a listening socket.

You don't *need* to connect the listening socket. You have just accepted  a socket from a client connection. You should do your I/O to that client with that socket.

In your second program:

```
if(setsockopt(socket_info, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&y, sizeof(y)) == -1) {
perror("set reuseaddr");
return -1;
    }
```

This is futile. The socket is already bound, implicitly, via the `connect()` call preceding.

```
    //binds socket
    if (bind(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    perror("Bind error");
    return 1;
    }

Bind error: Cannot assign requested address
```

You can't bind a socket that is already connected.

Nor can you bind a socket to a remote address.

Nor can you listen on a connected socket.

Nor can you accept from it. You don't *need* to bind, or listen, or accept from it. You are already connected to the peer.

In short your code doesn't make any sense whatsoever. You need to find a proper tutorial and study it.

```
incoming_message[strlen(incoming_message)-1] = 0;
```

This makes even less sense. Here you are searching for a trailing null byte (which may not even be there) and replacing the byte before it by ... a null byte. Why?